# Tags in contact reports

Tags: civireport

Using Civi 4.74 combined with Joomla 3.5

WE're looking to include tags in our contact reports but there's no obvious way to do so. What are we missing?

Comment: can you be more specific in terms of "our contact reports" - and the actual outcome you need - since there may be a work around such as setting up a Saved Export Mapping with the fields you want.

Comment: Contact reports as in...saved lists of our contacts. We want to be able to include in them what tags are assigned to them.

Comment: Hi Matt - i am not trying to be cute here. Do you mean CiviReports, or Saved Searches aka Smart Groups, or something else. There are many ways to construct or think of 'contact report'. If CiviReports, which specific reports? Thanks

Comment: Contacts menu > "Contact reports". I think "Civi Reports". Certainly not Smart Groups, that's something else entirely.

Comment: can you paste the part of the url that follows your domain, ie <yoursite>/civicrm/...

Comment: Confirmed...it is Civi Report.

Comment: Matt - I and others are happy to help other users of civicrm but please make it as easy as possible for us. One way you can do this is paste links. It looks like you might have done so and then removed it. I didn't need  your domain, just the bit starting civicrm/ - sorry if you though i needed to know your site too. alternatively go to a demo site and find the equivalent link eg http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/2?reset=1. Will put rest in as an answer

Comment: domain/admin/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/report/list&compid=99&reset=1

Comment: I think Matt is asking for a way to include the tags in the "tags" section of a contact's details in a standard CiviReport. That is, to be able to have a column that lists all the tags that this contact has, similar to how the tags are displayed in the Main Contact Summary Page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about eg http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/2?reset=1 then no there is no option via the UI to do so. A developer would be able to add such a feature I expect.

Meantime there are other options such as: you can use eg Advanced Search, find the contacts you want to export, select "Select fields for export" then in the Export Mapping you can set the Tags field, and it should include that data with all the contacts Tags in a single cell separated by a comma. eg

Irvin Deforest | Volunteer,Major Donor
alidacooper@airmail.biz | Volunteer,Major Donor

You can then save that Export for future use. I have done this on Demo - it is called Contacts and Tabs via "Select fields for export" and then look under "use Saved Mapping fields".

But demo site will flush in a few hours

HTH.